# Android- Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double java.lang.Double.doubleValue()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, firebase

There are two accounts in my app, family and elderly. And I want to retrieve the location of the elderly to the family account, then show it in a map. Now, I want to get the latitude and longitude. I have set the accounts in a pair.

Here is the database structure.

[image]

Update:

The updated code:

```
private Button logout;
private ImageButton buttonCurrent;
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseUser user;
private double longitude;
private double latitude;
private String currentUserId;
private com.google.firebase.database.Query mQueryMF;


//Our Map
private GoogleMap mMap;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    currentUserId = user.getUid();
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main__family);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    logout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logout);
    buttonCurrent = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonCurrent);


    buttonCurrent.setOnClickListener(this);

    logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity_Family.this, HomeActivity.class));
        }
    });


}
private void getCurrentLocation() {
   mQueryMF = mDatabase.child("users").child("familyId").equalTo(currentUserId);

    mQueryMF.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            latitude = 
dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue(Double.class);  
            longitude = 
dataSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue(Double.class);
            //String to display current latitude and longitude
            String msg = latitude + ", "+longitude;

            //Creating a LatLng Object to store Coordinates
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            //Adding marker to map
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(latLng) //setting position
                    .draggable(true) //Making the marker draggable
                    .title("Current Location")); //Adding a title

            //Moving the camera
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

            //Animating the camera
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });

}

//Function to move the map
/*private void moveMap() {




    //Displaying current coordinates in toast
    //Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}*/

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).draggable(true));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(this);
    mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    getCurrentLocation();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override
public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {
    //Clearing all the markers
    mMap.clear();

    //Adding a new marker to the current pressed position
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latLng)
            .draggable(true));
}

@Override
public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {

}

@Override
public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {

}

@Override
public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
    //Getting the coordinates
    latitude = marker.getPosition().latitude;
    longitude = marker.getPosition().longitude;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v == buttonCurrent){
        getCurrentLocation();
    }
}
```

The error happens in getting the latitude in getCurrentLocation function

Comment: I've rollbacked your last edit: please do not make your question a non-question: instead post your solution in an answer of its own.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `orderByChild()` method provided by the Firebase SDK, try this code instead of yours:

```
mQueryMF = mDatabase.child("users");
mQueryMF.orderByChild("familyId").equalTo(currentUserId)
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    // The snapshot contains the latitude and the longitude
                    latitude = dataSnapshot.getChild("latitude").getValue(double.class);
                    longitude = dataSnapshot.getChild("longitude").getValue(double.class);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix this, please use the following code:

```
mQueryMF = mDatabase.child("users").child("familyId").equalTo(currentUserId);

mQueryMF.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        double latitude = dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue(Double.class);
        double longitude = dataSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue(Double.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});
```

To get the data, you need to iterate over the `DataSnapshot` object and not on the `DatabaseReference` object. And you cannot use `getValue(double.class)`. **`double is a primitive not a class`**. The correct way is use `Double` class.

Comment: I have updated my question. Now, I can only get latitude and longitude 0.0. Which part of my code is wrong? Thank you.

Comment: It's null because you are using `latitude` and `longitude` outside `onDataChange()` method. Due the asynchronous behavior of this method those fields are null. You need to move all your logic inside `onDataChange()` or see my answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44152775/how-to-get-value-async-in-outside-method-ondatachange). Does it work with data data inside?

Comment: I move the moveMap() to getCurrentLocation()

Comment: I have moved the code(see my updated question),but the app doesn't work. When the function runs, the app quits. Sorry for my poor programming knowledge.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double java.lang.Double.doubleValue()' on a null object reference
                                                                                     at com.findmyelderly.findmyelderly.MainActivity_Family$2.onDataChange(MainActivity_Family.java:92)12-04 14:22:02.345 13612-13641/com.findmyelderly.findmyelderly W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.

Comment: This is not a Firebase error. Please share that code.

Comment: The error happens in getting the latitude in getCurrentLocation function

Comment: I cannot see in your code the `doubleValue()` method. Where is it?

Comment: I do not use it. The error says it is a virtual method,so I think the returning latitude is null. But there is a value in firebase, I don't know why it returns null.

Comment: Try to use this line of code: `mQueryMF = mDatabase.child("users").orderByChild("familyId").equalTo(currentUserId);`

Comment: I try to use if (latitude == null) {....} and  if (dataSnapshot == null) {..}to test. It gives me latitude is null. When I want to print the content of dataSnapshot  using dataSnapshot.getValue().toString(); It says it is a null object and crash. I am so puzzled.....

Comment: Is your `cu‌​rrentUserId` returning the correct user id?

Comment: I have solved the problem by adding   for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {...} under onDataChange.