# Retrieve location from Firebase with a UID and put in Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-api

I am trying to save and retrieve a location from `Firebase` and put it in Google Maps. The latitude and longitude value is under a user id, because it will be used for the location of a specific user. Saving the location is successful but I can't retrieve it. I'm trying to retrieve it but I keep getting

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'double java.lang.Double.doubleValue()' on a null object reference"
>   error.

Any way to solve or do this? Thank you in advance.

Here's the code for saving the location:

```
    profDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Profile");

       if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null){

                    String userid = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                    final DatabaseReference locDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                            .getReferenceFromUrl("https://sholoco-9cf1e.firebaseio.com/Profile/" + userid);

                    profDatabase.child(userid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            String stallname = dataSnapshot.child("StallName").getValue().toString();

                            Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new
                                    MarkerOptions().position(point).title(stallname));
                            final LatLng latlng = marker.getPosition();

                            mSaveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    //DatabaseReference newPost = profDatabase.push();
                                    //newPost.setValue(latlng);

                                    String latkey = "latitude";
                                    double latvalue = latlng.latitude;
                                    DatabaseReference child = locDatabase.child(latkey);
                                    child.setValue(latvalue);

                                    String longkey = "longitude";
                                    double longvalue = latlng.longitude;
                                    child = locDatabase.child(longkey);
                                    child.setValue(longvalue);
                                }
                            });
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
```

And here's my code for retrieving the location:

```
profDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Profile");
        if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {

            String userid = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
            profDatabase.child(userid).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    double latt = (double) dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue();
                    double longg = (double) dataSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue();
                    String stallname = dataSnapshot.child("StallName").getValue().toString();

                    LatLng newLocation = new LatLng(latt, longg);

                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(newLocation)
                            .title(stallname));
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
```

A screenshot from my database:

[image: firebase database screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` instead `addChildEventListener()` ?

To get the values without `userid`:
Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46651960/4653447

```
 FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Profile").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
         for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            double latt = (double) snapshot.child("latitude").getValue();
            double longg = (double) snapshot.child("longitude").getValue();
           //store this data in list
         }
    }
```

Comment: Btw, what do you mean store the data in list? (Sorry I ask a lot)

Comment: I deleted the other users without a location and left the user who has a location and it worked. But I get an error when I create and try to save a location.

Comment: When I try to save a location of another user, the app crashes and I get this error:

_java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double java.lang.Double.doubleValue()' on a null object reference_

on this line (with userid): 

`double latt = (double) dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue();`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to type cast latitude and longitude to `double`, instead pass `Double.class` as a parameter to `getValue()`

```
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                double latt = dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue(Double.class);
                double longg = dataSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue(Double.class);
                String stallname = dataSnapshot.child("StallName").getValue().toString();

                LatLng newLocation = new LatLng(latt, longg);

                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(newLocation)
                        .title(stallname));
            }
```

Refere to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47605637/7382665)

Comment: That was actually my first code but it still didn't work